# determine repo size?

Tags: svn

I'm wondering if there's a way to determine the size of my svn repo when I don't have access to the actual hard disk that it's stored on?  I'm asking specifically because our project is being hosted on google code.  There's a 1GB limit.  I doubt we're close to it, but I really don't know and would like to keep an eye on it.

Comment: Out of interest, where on Google Groups is the 1Gb repo size documented?

Comment: @Neil:  The main Google Project Hosting page (http://code.google.com/projecthosting/) says there's a 2GB limit.

Comment: @James Thanks, I was looking in the FAQ (surely one of the worst around).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnsync.html) to create a clone of the repository on your hard disk, and measure it's size.

This won't be exact, though, as the size may vary depending on the format of the repository (e.g. bsdb or fs backend, svn version, sharding, ...) and other factors (e.g. clustering). But it should give you a good idea of the size of the repository.

Comment: +1 for good advice.  Even though Google is not likely to go out of business soon, using svnsync also provides you with a much needed backup repository of your SVN server.  Not backing up your repository could cause issues should you ever get locked out of your Google account.